# When i need to call SaveChanges method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

Assume i have a few save methods. What is better way call `_context.SaveChanges()` in the end of each method or move this method in global.ascx file and call it only time in the end of app lifecycle? Is it important for perfomance purpose?

I use EF and ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should call it a the end of each update method. Otherwise if you've changed the object and not saved it, the object won't be updated in the database until the application ends. If another process requests this object from the database it won't have the latest changes. If this process also modifies this object and then saving it at the end of the application you'd even get an OptimisticConcurrencyException.

Answer (score 0):

Context is not thread safe.  So multiple changes to the context could throw an error.

The way I handle this is either one of two ways.  Controller/Repository and per method.  I have not seen any performance hit either way.  Most of the books I have read lean towards the repository style unless you only have 2-3 methods that use EF.

I define something like this before my class

```
SomeContext context = new SomeContext();
```

then have I have a method like this.

```
public void Save()
{
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you want to do it per method something like this

```
using (var context = new SomeContext())
{
  // somecode
}
```

Comment: Ok, but then i recreate context(and sql connection) every time when i call save method. I think it is not good for perfomance(if i have more then one save method)